# How to get the value of an anchor in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am displaying a series of messages from database and I want to get their message_id which I stored in anchor value.

**Blade**

```
@foreach ($mesaje as $mesaj)
    @foreach ($users as $user)
        @if ($user->user_id == $mesaj->expeditor_id && Auth::user()->user_id == $mesaj->destinatar_id && $mesaj->viz_exp != 1)
        <div class="chill">
            <span class="marker">*</span>
            <a name="username" value="{{$mesaj->mesaj_id}}"
               style="line-height:30px;position:relative;padding:16px 18px 16px 120px;display: inline; height: 100%;"
               href="/profil/{{Auth::user()->username}}/mesaje/citeste-mesaj/{{ $mesaj->mesaj_id }}">{{$user->username}}</a>

            <a name="subiect" value="{{$mesaj->mesaj_id}}" style="padding:16px 18px 16px 220px;display: inline; height: 100%;"
               href="/profil/{{Auth::user()->username}}/mesaje/citeste-mesaj/{{ $mesaj->mesaj_id }}"> {{$mesaj->subiect}}</a>

            <a name="data_mesajului" value="{{$mesaj->mesaj_id}}"
               style="padding:16px 170px 16px 160px;display:inline; height: 100%;"
               href="/profil/{{Auth::user()->username}}/mesaje/citeste-mesaj/{{ $mesaj->mesaj_id }}">{{$mesaj->data_mesajului}}</a>

            <a name="{{$mesaj->mesaj_id}}" value="{{$mesaj->mesaj_id}}"
               style="padding:10px 100px 10px -50px;display:inline; height: 100%;"
               href="/profil/{{Auth::user()->username}}/mesaje/sterge-mesajd/{{ $mesaj->mesaj_id }}">X</a>
        </div>
        <hr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$me = DB::table('mesaje')->where('citit', '=', '1')->first();
if ($me->mesaj_id == 'value of the anchor element')
{
    //do smth
}
?>
```

Basically I am trying to get the message where 'citit' = 1 and the 'mesaj_id' = the id of the message that is displayed, does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: A couple of observations: 1) You don't need the `'='` argument in `where()` calls. 2) Your conditional, `if($me->citit == 1)` is redundant because you're already checking that value in the query. As to your question, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Maybe you're looking for [Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships)?

Comment: i display the messages with an id.i want to check if that id == the database id

Comment: more speciffic: i have anchor with a value, how can i get that value ?

Comment: hmm the problem is i want to make the check if that value == the id in the database and i dont think i can do that in javascript.

Comment: i made the question more clear i hope by changing the php a bit.